# Creating a Database in SQL+?

Tags: sql

In SQL+, I first connect to the server I have been given;

CONNECT/
Connected.

However, when trying to create a Database I get the following:

CREATE DATABASE Project3;
CREATE DATABASE failed
database already mounted

I've also tried - STARTUP NOMOUNT but only states I have insufficient privileges.

Is there something i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You most probably want to create a new user, not a database.

Answer (score 0):

In case this is Oracle you are talking about (Oracles default CLI is called SQL*Plus), this means that a database has already been configured on the server. Oracle only uses a single database per server instance. Inside those databases are schema's, and that is where your database objects will be stored.

See the below quote from: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28301/install.htm#ADMQS002

```
After you create a database, either during installation or as a standalone 
operation, you do not need to create another. Each Oracle instance works 
with a single database only. Rather than requiring that you to create 
multiple databases to accommodate different applications, Oracle Database 
uses a single database, and accommodates multiple applications by enabling 
you to separate data into different schemas within the single database.
```